# On the Application of the Einstein-Brillouin-Keller (EBK) Method

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential, schroedinger-equation, semiclassical

Consider the Born-Sommerfeld quantization condition (modified) [see [Einstein–Brillouin–Keller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Brillouin%E2%80%93Keller_method) (EBK)]

$$I_{i} = \frac{1}{2\pi}S_{i} =  \frac{1}{2\pi}\oint p_{i} dq_{i} = \hbar \left(n_{i} + \frac{\mu_{i}}{4} + \frac{b_{i}}{2} \right),\tag{1}$$

when applied to the semi-harmonic oscillator with potential,

$$V(x) = \frac{1}{2}m\omega^{2}x^{2}\text{ for }x>0\text{ and }V(x) = \infty\text{ otherwise.} \tag{2}$$

We here have a turning point at $x=x_{1}$, say $x_{1} = a$ and obtain the expression for this as

$$a = \frac{1}{\omega}\sqrt{\frac{2E}{m}}.\tag{3}$$

We can find that upon integration, $\int_{0}^{a}k(x) dx = \frac{\pi E}{2\hbar \omega}$. Now, in the quantization condition, the Maslov indices take the values $\mu = 1$ and $b = 1$  for the reasons that there is one turning point and since there is one reflection at the hard wall (and also since $\Psi(0) = 0$ holds) respectively. Upon doing this substitution, we get

$$I_{x} = \frac{1}{2\pi}S_{x} = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int p(x) dx = \left(n + \frac{3}{4} \right)\hbar,\tag{4}$$

and this, when equated to what was found previously doesn't give the correct expression for $E_{n}$. This seems to work only when we take $S_{x} = 2\int p(x) dx$, since this correctly gives $E_{n} = \left(2n+\frac{3}{2}\right)\hbar\omega$. How do we account for this factor of "$2$"? Is this to do with phase changes due to the reflections or that we take into consideration both possibilities of solutions with $E<V(x)$ and $E>V(x)$ at the turning point?

Links to other questions about EKB:
for an outline of general features:
[1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/299306/),
for derivation and additional references: [2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/281816/), about the Maslov index in Bohr-Sommerfeld quantization condition:  [3](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/146130/), for references: [4](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64212/).

Comment: Hi Spoilt Milk, I removed your second question as Phys.SE works best with 1 question per post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Eq. (1) is for a closed orbit, i.e. the particle traverses the interval $[0,a]$ twice, i.e. forth & back. This explains the factor 2.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now. So each turning point provides an "additional" phase or so to speak right? Also, could you please provide some references where quantization for higher dimensional integrable systems is dealt with in detail.

Comment: Check out http://chaosbook.org/